# Equivalent of L.Class.include() with TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, typescript-typings, leaflet.draw

In JavaScript (with Leaflet), I could implement some custom functionnalities using `L.Class.include()` as written in the documentation :

> Including more functionality in an existing class with L.Class.include()
>   Adding new methods and options
>   Changing some methods
>   Using addInitHook to run extra constructor code.

**This works :**

```
 L.Rectangle.include({
    contains: function (markers: L.Marker[]) {
      const markersContained: boolean[] = [];
      markers.forEach(marker => {
        console.log(marker);
        markersContained.push(this.getBounds().contains(marker.getLatLng()));
      })
      return markersContained;
    }
  });
```

Now I'm trying to implement the same in an Angular4 Application with TypeScript, but the `include()` function doesn't seem to be Typed in the `@types/leaflet`

The thing is that my code is in a `.ts` file that is tailored for `Leaflet.Draw` plugin, so I had to initialize the file this way :

```
declare const L: any;
import 'leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw-src';
```

instead of the regular

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
```

due to the fact that the `Leaflet.Draw` plugin has no `@types`, hence I can't import the regular leaflet types (Otherwise, `new L.Control.Draw()` would make a compilation error).

**This breaks at compilation time :**

```
  map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, (geometry: L.LayerEvent) => {
    const layer = geometry.layer;
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);

    // Set an array containing all the markers
    const markers = LeafletService.prototype.jsonToArray(layerGroup.getLayers());

    // ===> Property 'contains' does not exist on type 'Layer'.
    const result = geometry.layer.contains(markers);
    console.log('result => ', result);
  });
```

and obviously, this works if I set my geometry type as `any`, but I'd like to use the `L.LayerEvent` type if possible, and want to know how I could use the TypeScript syntax to use Leaflet `include()` method correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR :** I have to use `any` unless they type `Leaflet.Draw`...

Okay so it was quite obvious in the end...

Because of `Leaflet.Draw` which has no types, I have to `declare const L: any` to avoid compilation errors when integrating the `Leaflet.Draw` plugin with `Leaflet`.

So obviously, when I call `L.Rectangle`, since L is of type `any`, I can't possibly use the typed `include()` method from `Leaflet` (I do use the actual method at runtime, but I can't make TypeScript aware of it for compilation time).

It's only logical that the geometry returned from the `Leaflet.Draw` event doesn't know about the new `contains()` method that I added since it is not linked to the actual `L.Rectangle` leaflet type.